# How to send data from one digital twin to another?

Tags: bosch-iot-suite

Let's assume

- I have created two digital twins in bosch-iot-things.

  - **ENGINE TWIN**:
    Digital twin for Engine.(engine temperature, oil level, etc)
  - **VEHICLE TWIN**: 
    Digital twin for Entire vehicle.(contains location, speed, engine temperature,
    etc)
- Created a connection between bosch-iot-things and sensors using bosch-iot-hub.

Now engine temperature sensor, sends data to ENGINE TWIN, and i want this data to be automatically updated in VEHICLE TWIN.

- **Question #1**:
  *so is it possible to achieve one digital twin(ENGINE TWIN) can send data to another digital twin(VEHICLE TWIN)?*
- **Question #2**: 
  *If yes how to configure it to send data automatically once it receives data from sensor?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible out-of-the-box.
From a "digital twin" pattern, one digital twin mirrors one physical device/asset.
I would suggest that to model your twins close to the real world devices - your most powerful device aggregating different capabilities would be the vehicle.
The "vehicle" twin contains (amonst others) an "engine" feature.

If you want to stick to the "several twins per physical asset" pattern you are on your own in syncing/copying the data from one twin to another.